# Entity previous status in Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

i have a doubt. Probably it is because I am a newbie in symfony.
I have an entity with a status and I show it in a form that the status can be changed.
In the controller i need the previous status to compare with new status to do some actions.
When I do bind I cannot access to previous status for this $entity,

```
$editForm = $this->createForm(new StatusType(), $entity);
$editForm->bind($request);
```

How can I access to these previous data?

Best Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there is a better way, but you can use:

```
$editForm = $this->createForm(new StatusType(), $entity);
$entity_before = clone $entity; //you can do it before your createform 
$editForm->bind($request);
```

Comment: Hello, it doesn't work because $entity and $entity_before are pointers to the same object. It was my first idea.Thanks anyway!

Comment: Are you sure? Did you checked? When you do $editForm->bind($request); you miss the origin entity and both entities point to the same object.

Comment: I just checked and yes, I have $entity_before not modified from my database, en $entity have the form changes

Comment: I don´t understand then. I don´t need update in database $entity_before I only need to keep duplicate entity to check the previous status (status is a relation ManytoOne with a table named StatusTypes). Thanks for your help

Comment: I don't know your level so sorry if it seems obvious for you:
With a var_dump( $entity); var_dump($entity_before); after your bind() method do you have still the same objects after changing some fields in the forms?

Comment: My doubt is solved. In this post talks exactly about my doubt. It wasn't enough with clone I should overwrite this method to clone properly my objetct. Thanks! http://www.epsilon-eridani.com/cubic/ap/cubic.php/pag/PHP5---Constructor-de-copia-71.html